# Cmd / windows key with Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: external-keyboard, remote-access

I am trying to use Chrome Remote Desktop on a tablet with Android 5.1.1 to remotely access my work iMac. I have a Bluetooth keyboard, and the problem is that I'm unable to use the *cmd* key on my Bluetooth keyboard to do things like *cmd-c* or *cmd-tab* when connected to the iMac, which make the whole thing practically unusable.

I suspect that Android is intercepting this key for a feature I've seen referred to as "Quick Launch", so Chrome Remote Desktop maybe doesn't even know I pressed that key. Is there a way on Android for the *cmd* key to "work, so I can do things like *cmd-c* and *cmd-tab* in Chrome Remote Desktop? If not, is this possible with another "remote desktop" app, or is that a limitation of the OS?